# How do I form these GET requests using libcurl?

Tags: c++, curl, authentication, web, libcurl

See the following GET request headers. I would like some direction regarding forming these GET requests using libcurl in C++.

```
GET url.aspx?TabID=100000021 HTTP/1.1
Host: url.net
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://url/Login.aspx?BackToStartPage=true
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: erJOJPQYCFBMNUJDDYWOH5; ASP.NET_SessionId=ickaamclvh45; BIGipServer~url~Flexnet-url-Prod.app~url-Prod_pool=rd1o00006a0do80; WebPortalSession=77d0601a4_1; LoginPageCookie=http://url/Login.aspx?CurrentUserLanguageId=1033&CurrentUserTimeZoneId=1129; .ASPXAUTH=92C511D2B670AE9DDC3D55A88BBEF6CAF16FBBF0BFFFB016C20B655BAB1B54428F9C55A8430F806F74211354557A8A918DFD8FE9589BF3F95D0340180E89806C4BDF7813CCD5DC027349F8714B1A319C1E51E8C43



GET url.aspx?TabID=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: url.net
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http:/url.net/Login.aspx?BackToStartPage=true
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: &LGN=MIYDMMBQGUZTS; ASP.NET_SessionId=ickaax45p; url~url~url-url-Prod.app~url-url-Prod_pool=rd1o0000o80; WebPortalSession=77d0601a9_1; LoginPageCookie=http://url.net/Login.aspx?CurrentUserLanguageId=1033&CurrentUserTimeZoneId=1129; .ASPXAUTH=7516499A62192592C485B17AF1D3BDB25DBDE26DF6A1FC179CC3658F3AD1E74E32
```

Comment: Asking for tutorials is off-topic for StackOverflow. The [libcurl API](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is fully documented, and includes examples. What EXACTLY are you having trouble figuring out from it?

Comment: CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://url.net/PerformTask.aspx?TabID=100000021");
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1L); 
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0");
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);  
             This is what I have for the 1st get request. I can't fit what I have for both GETs bc of char limit. I still cannot get it to work.

Comment: CURL *one = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(one, CURLOPT_URL, "http://url.net/TransactionPage.aspx?TabID=0 HTTP/1.1");
 curl_easy_setopt(one, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
 curl_easy_setopt(one, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);
 curl_easy_setopt(one, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1L); 
 curl_easy_setopt(one, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0");
 curl_easy_setopt(one, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

Comment: please [edit] your question to include details like that, don't post them in comments